# What happened to YouTube comment replies?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

Ever since Google forced users on YouTube to use Google+, I have been unable to find replies to comments anywhere. They aren't as notifications, and they aren't in my inbox, because that doesn't exist anymore. So what happened to them? Is it a feature they completely removed?

Answer (score 1):

Inbox still exists, but the links to it are well-buried

1. use the Switch Account link in YouTube so you're on the right profile.
2. go to https://www.youtube.com/inbox

Answer (score 0):

There is a BELL which will give you comment updates.
http://uigalleries.com/previews/xiv7sT1Nj-google-notifications-christmas-holiday-bell-icon.png

Comment: Always add essential part of the link in answer.